# Fit quick launch within window

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, quick-launch

I'm trying to get the quick launch to fit the browser window size. As you can see from the following screenshot, currently the quicklaunch is shorter than the window (see the yellow area just below it).
[image]

This is the css used to set scroll and height:

```
.ms-quicklaunch-navmgr
    {
        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:650px;
    }
```

Currently my attempts to make it fit the available height have failed. Can anyone provide some guidance on the matter? Should I try to edit the masterpage, fix it with some custom css or else?

Comment: Hi - I have tried to make your question more clear (since there was some close votes on it). Can you please further improve it by clarifying what exactly have you tried? I don't get if the posted css snippet is your attempt at fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot I believe you're using SharePoint 2010. Here's some CSS I just pulled from an old SharePoint 2010 design project

```
body #s4-leftpanel-content,
.ms-quicklaunchouter
{
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Played a little bit in a virtual test environment and got the following working better than the version above:

```
body #s4-bodyContainer,
.s4-widecontentarea,
body #s4-leftpanel,
body #s4-leftpanel-content,
.ms-quicklaunchouter
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Let us know if that works better for you.

Comment: Closer but it extends past the window and cause the entire page to require scrolling. Which isn't what I want when there's nothing in the main content area.

Comment: See my updated answer. Looks like the second version is working better without the issue you were facing.